# Collection of case class instances preserving uniqueness of a single field

Tags: scala, collections, case-class

Suppose you have a case class `SearchQualifier` with two fields, `left` and `right`. It can be added to an instance of some `SearchQuery` class to qualify a search (e.g. `SearchQualifier("date", "January 1, 2000")`).

```
case class SearchQualifier(left: String, right: String)
```

Now, say you had a collection of `SearchQualifiers`. If you add a new qualifier to the collection with the same `left` as another, your intention is to override the previous value. For example:

```
qualifiers = qualifiers + Qualifier("date", "January 1, 2000")
...
qualifiers = qualifiers + Qualifier("date", "December 31, 1999") // override
```

Is there a clean way to preserve the uniqueness of qualifiers based on `left`?

My current approach uses a `Map[String, Qualifier]` where the map key is `left`, but it feels like a hack:

```
map = map + (qual.left -> qual)
```

Ideally, I would prefer `Set`-like behaviour. However, I don't think it would be correct to override `equals` to only check `left`, because `SearchQualifier("date", "January 1, 2000")` and `SearchQualifier("date", "December 31, 1999")` are *not* equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a `Map` is the perfect data structure for you here, not a hack at all.  It makes perfect sense to think of a `Map` as being basically a `Set` in which each element is tied to a value.  In fact, `Map` has a method `.keySet` in which the keys are return to you as a `Set`, which supports this argument.  As you pointed out, overriding `.equals` just to get that behavior in a `Set` would be indeed confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple solution will be to use `TreeSet`

```
  val searchQualifierOrderingByLeft = new Ordering[SearchQualifier] {
    override def compare(x: SearchQualifier, y: SearchQualifier): Int = 
      if (x.left == y.left) 0 else 1
  }

  val ts = TreeSet[SearchQualifier](SearchQualifier("l1", "r1"),
                                    SearchQualifier("l1", "r2"),
                                    SearchQualifier("l2", "r1"))(searchQualifierOrderingByLeft)

      println(ts) // TreeSet(SearchQualifier(l1,r2), SearchQualifier(l2,r1))
```